# Jquery slideToggle not working on sidebar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I can't seem to figure out why my Jquery code is not executing when I click on the li. It is probably something very simple that I can't spot...

HTML:

```js
$(function() {
  ("#btn-more-nav").click(function() {
    $("#dropdown-nav").slideToggle();
  })
});
```

```css
ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #999;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

.dropdown-nav {
  padding-left: 10px;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
}

.dropdown-nav li {
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="active"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="profile.php">Profile</a></li>
  <li><a href="notifications.php">Notifications</a></li>
  <li><a href="messages.php">Messages</a></li>
  <li id="btn-more-nav"><a href="">More<i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
  <ul class="dropdown-nav" id="dropdown-nav">
    <li><a href="logout.php">Logout<i class="fa fa-sign-out" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="settings.php">Settings<i class="fa fa-cog" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You can't have a `<ul>` as a child of another `<ul>`. You're also missing the `$` on your click handler

Comment: You need to wrap the child `ul` with `li`

Comment: Works for me. https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/83kq6hns/ What error do you get?

Comment: @j08691 it works for you because you didn't copy the html exactly as they had it. You've wrapped the child UL in a LI, they did not.

Comment: @TheMuffinMan The OP *had* posted that they fixed the typos and it still didn't work. Guess they deleted that comment. Although even with the invalid HTML as posted, it still works. Try it for yourself.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea why.. but even if I literally copy the code in that jsfiddle it continues to fail..

Comment: You're missing the `$` in front of `("#btn-more-nav").click(function()`

Comment: And you need to pass the `event` to your click handler and disable that with `event.preventDefault();` https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QvojRY

Comment: Thanks for that.. Now it works, I really have no idea how it's working on JSfiddle  without that line of code..